# How to get all messages from the queue in php-amqplib (RabbitMQ)?

Tags: php, queue, rabbitmq

Currently, I'm using https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib and I've read a lot of examples in this repository but I still don't understand how to get all the messages from the queue?

I just need to receive some messages, group them by value and perform an action.

Is it possible to do with RabbitMQ at all?

How can I implement this in php?

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php

use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;

$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('rabbitmq', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$channel = $connection->channel();
$queueName = 'task_queue';
$channel->queue_declare($queueName, false, true, false, false);
$result = $channel->basic_get($queueName);

var_dump($result);

$channel->close();
$connection->close();
```

Comment: Thanks, some day I will check this!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get all messages currently available by calling single method.
Closest possible solution is by using `basic_consume` method.

For example:

```
function process_message($message)
{
    echo "Received message '" . $message->body . "'\n";

    /** Do your grouping here **/

}

$channel->basic_consume($queue, '', false, false, false, false, 'process_message');

// Loop as long as the channel has callbacks registered
while (count($channel->callbacks)) {
    $channel->wait();
}
```

You can check [official RabbitMQ PHP tutorial](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/blob/master/php/receive.php) or [demo from php-amqplib](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/blob/master/demo/amqp_consumer_fanout_1.php).